# jQuery: How to get to a particular child of a parent?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, parent, siblings

To give a simplified example, I've got the following block repeated on the page lots of times (it's dynamically generated):

```
<div class="box">
   <div class="something1"></div>
   <div class="something2">
      <a class="mylink">My link</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

When clicked, I can get to the parent of the link with:

```
$(".mylink").click(function() {
   $(this).parents(".box").fadeOut("fast");
});
```

However... I need to get to the `<div class="something1">` of that particular parent.

Basically, can someone tell me how to refer to a higher-level sibling without being able to refer to it directly? Let's call it big brother. A direct reference to the big brother's class name would cause every instance of that element on the page to fade out - which is not the desired effect.

I've tried:

```
parents(".box .something1") ... no luck.
parents(".box > .something1") ... no luck.
siblings() ... no luck.
```

Anyone? Thanks.

Comment: Anurag's answer might not seem like the right one -it certainly made me stop and think- but it's pointing out a blatant typo in your code that's causing your selector to fail. The selector, in jQuery, is `.parent()` *not* `.parents()`

Comment: @ricebowl: Wrong.  http://api.jquery.com/parents/

Comment: @ricebowl... parent() would give me div something2, so I need parents() to get to div box.

Comment: Ah; my apologies. Umm...I don't know whether it's best to leave my ignorance on display, or delete the error to avoid upsetting anyone else... =| Still, at least I've learned something useful today; that's the point, right..? =)

Comment: @ricebowl, no worries, thanks for contributing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the child of an element being dragged with jQuery UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986532/how-to-get-the-child-of-an-element-being-dragged-with-jquery-ui)

Comment: I couldn't have asked this question better.

Answer (score 164, accepted):

Calling `.parents(".box .something1")` will return all parent elements that match the selector `.box .something`.  In other words, it will return parent elements that are `.something1` and are inside of `.box`.

You need to get the children of the closest parent, like this:

```
$(this).closest('.box').children('.something1')
```

This code calls [`.closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to get the innermost parent matching a selector, then calls `.children` on that parent element to find the uncle you're looking for.

Comment: I know this is a bit old but isn't it better in this case to use **parent()** rather than **closest()** as I imagine there is more tree traversal with **closest()**?

Comment: @acSlater: He _needs_ tree traversal.  `parent()` is the wrong element.

Comment: Ah yes it's parent().parent() that Tom needs sorry! :)

Comment: @acSlater: Yes; that would work.  However, it makes the Javascript much more coupled to the HTML structure.  `.closest(...)` is more resilient, and more readable too.

Comment: I was just saying I realised he needed parent->parent, I agree with you closest is best for this scenario

Comment: In case anyone is wondering: after you've found the right parent using .closest(), if you're looking for a child element that is NOT a direct child (but a child of a child, for example), just use .find() in place of .children.

Comment: For my code I needed  `$(this).closest('.box').prev('.something1')` but this answer helped me figure that out

Answer (score 21):

```
$(this).parent()
```

Tree traversal is fun

```
$(this).parent().siblings(".something1");

$(this).parent().prev(); // if you always want the parent's previous sibling

$(this).parents(".box").children(".something1");
```

And much more ways, you might find these [docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/) helpful.

Comment: Thanks but wasn't looking for the parent, but rather another child of parent (or grandparent actually).

Comment: Hehe... its a family affair indeed.

Answer (score 17):

This will find the first parent with class `box` then find the first child class with regex matching `something` and get the id.

```
$(".mylink").closest(".box").find('[class*="something"]').first().attr("id")
```

Answer (score 7):

If I understood your problem correctly, `$(this).parents('.box').children('.something1')` Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 5):

You could use `.each()` with `.children()` and a selector within the parenthesis:

```
//Grab Each Instance of Box.
$(".box").each(function(i){

    //For Each Instance, grab a child called .something1. Fade It Out.
    $(this).children(".something1").fadeOut();
});
```