# Trigger button on drop

Tags: jquery

I have the following script

```
$(function() {
        $(".draggable").draggable({
                revert: true
        });
        $("#droppable").droppable({
                over: function() {
                       $(this).css('backgroundColor', '#cedae3');
                },
                out: function() {
                        $(this).css('backgroundColor', '#CDAF95');
                },
                drop: function(e, ui) {

                      $(ui.draggable).trigger('click');

                }
        });
});
```

I have **multiple draggables**, everyone in one td. In each of the draggables I've got a button.

How can I trigger the button **from the dropped draggable** on drop? This isn't working: `$(ui.draggable).trigger('click');` Does anyone has any suggestions?

```
<td class="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
                        <form action="index.php" method="post">
                            <?php echo $produs['nume_produs']; ?>
                            <hr />
                            Pret: <?php echo $produs['pret']; ?> lei
                            <br />

                            <input type="hidden" name="nume_produs" value="<?php echo $produs['nume_produs']; ?>" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="produs_id" value="<?php echo $produs['id']; ?>" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="pret" value="<?php echo $produs['pret']; ?>" />
                            <input type="submit" name="adauga" class="adauga" value="Adauga"/>
                        </form>
                    <td>
```

Comment: on which dom you want to trigger click event...because you need to specify selector inplace of ui.draggable..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$(ui.draggable).trigger('click');` would trigger a click on your **draggable**. You want to trigger a click on a button, so use

`$("#your-button").trigger('click');`

If you have **multiple draggables**, to get always the submit button from the right draggable use:

`ui.draggable.children('input').attr('type', 'submit')`

**Edit:**

Beside: `class="draggable" class="ui-widget-content"`

should be `class="draggable ui-widget-content"`

Comment: $('input[name="adauga"]').trigger('click'); i've tried this ... it's working but i want the button within the div... this triggers me only the first button in my div list

Comment: have you got more than one button in your div? if not, just use `.draggable button`, otherwise, why give your button an id or a class, and use this as selector

Comment: or you could simply post some of your html, and we could tell you

Comment: i've updated the code.... well i want the button with the name "adauga" to pe triggerd

Comment: use `$(".draggable form input[type=submit]").trigger('click');`

Comment: it still triggers me the first button.. from the first <td>

Comment: i am doing a foreach before the td... so i have lots of it, with products and stuff. if it was one it shouldn't have been any problem

Comment: still doesn't do the job:-?

Comment: thats an important information you should not keep back. For how to select children of ui.draggable, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986532/how-to-get-the-child-of-an-element-being-dragged-with-jquery-ui

Comment: This will do the job `ui.draggable.children('input').attr('type', 'submit')`

Answer (score 1):

Don't you need to select the actual button element within the ui.draggable div? So in this case, try:

> $(#adauga).trigger('click');

Comment: yes... i've tried this $('input[name="adauga"]').trigger('click'); but this triggers me only one button within my class.. and i need the actual button within the div that was dragged