# How exactly does this JQuery script work? and how can I modify it to select a specific object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am absolutly new in JavaScript and jQuery and I have the following problem.

I have the following jQuery script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("thead.opening").click(function () {
            $(this).next().slideToggle('slow', function () {
                $(this).prev("thead.opening").toggleClass("active");
                $("thead.opening").find(".imgAccordion").attr("src", "img/arrow.gif");
                $("thead.active").find(".imgAccordion").attr("src", "img/arrow_down.gif");
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

and in my HTML I have something like this:

```
<table class="standard-table-cls table-header-cls">
        <thead class="opening active">
        <tr>
            <th>
                <img class="imgAccordion" src="img/arrow_down.gif"/>
                Ricerca Flussi (la funzione e' consentita per flussi inferiori alle 300 fatture)
            </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody class="expanded">
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 100em;">
                    SHOW SOMETHING
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>

...........................................................
...........................................................
...........................................................


<table class="standard-table-cls table-header-cls">

    <thead class="opening">
        <tr>
            <th>
               <img class="imgAccordion" src="img/arrow.gif"/>
               Ricerca Fatture
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody class="expanded" style="display: none;">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 100em;">
                 SHOW SOMETHING ELSE
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

<table>
```

As you can see in my code there is 2 different tables both having the same classes (`standard-table-cls table-header-cls`).

When I click on the `thead` of one of these table it seems to me that the previous script is perfromed (it is right or am I saying wrong assertion?).

I think so because this statment:

```
 $("thead.opening").click(function () {.......
```

means something like: perform the body of the defined function() when the user click on any `thead` element having `class=opening`.

Is it my reasoning correct?

No my doubt (and also the related problem) is: how jQuery know what is the specific `thead.opening` clicked by the user (the one related to the first table or the one related to the second table)?

What exactly represent the `$(this)` element in the previous script? (it is the selected object or what?)

And finally, how can I modify the previous script to obtain the reference of the inner `tbody` of the same table of the `thead.opening` clicked?

Tnx

Comment: First `this` is table `thead`, second is `tbody` (jQuery [next method](https://api.jquery.com/next/) returns the immediately following sibling). You can easily output it to console and see: `console.log( $(this) )`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> this statment ... perform the body of the defined function() when the user click on any thead element having class=opening.

yes that is correct.

> how JQuery know what is the specific thead.opening clicked by the user

the answer lies in:  **$(this)**.next().slideToggle('slow', function ()....

> What exactly represent the $(this) element in the previous script?

the object which is clicked.

> obtain the reference of the inner tbody of the same table of the thead.opening clicked

use something similar to the following in the click handler:

```
$(this).closest('.standard-table-cls').children('tbody')
```

reference: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398947/jquery-how-to-get-to-a-particular-child-of-a-parent) and [here](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'll keep this as short as possible but `this` is the scope in the current function. In elements, its an element. So for you?

```
$("thead.opening").click
```

runs a function. So the `$(this)` is the `thread.opening` that was actually clicked.

### [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051782/jquery-this-vs-this)

Comment: Ok, great explaination but how can I select the tbody element of the thread.opening clicked? Can I do something like $(this).next() ? or what?

Answer (score 0):

`$("thead.opening")` returns a array of elements that match the selector, in your case the two separate table headers that have the class `opening` added to them.

the `.click()` assigns a click event handler to each of the elements returned by the selector. In your case to both the table headers.

`$(this)` refers to element which invoked the event in the event handler.

The code `$(this).next().slideToggle(` is already referencing the next sibling of the thead - in your HTMLs case, the tbody.

Comment: Ok, so the $("thead.opening").click is the thead having class="opening" that was clicked? is it right? But what can I do to select its relative tbody element? Can I use something like $(this).next() to select it? or what?

Comment: Have you started playing with the console in your browser? Hit F12 and you'll be able to run the javascript directly in the browser. If you're using firefox then I recommend using Firebug to help you along. You should be able to use $(this).next() to gain a reference to the next sibling in the DOM - in your case, the tbody. 

You've also got options like using $(this).parent('table').find('tfoot') to go up a level in the hierarchy and then find the footer of the table (if you had one).

Answer (score 0):

> When I click on the thead of one of these table it seems to me that
>   the previous script is perfromed (it is right or am I saying wrong
>   assertion?).

You are right

> Is it my reasoning correct?

This is correct

> What exactly represent the $(this) element in the previous script? (it
>   it the selected object or what?)

`$(this)` referes to the element invoking the function `$("thead.opening").click(function () {});`, so `$(this)` is equal to `$("thead.opening")`, where `thead.opening` is the exact element clicked (not the other `thead.opening` in your document).

> And finnally, how can modify the previous script to obtain the
>   reference of the inner tbody of the same table of the thead.opening
>   clicked?

`$(this).next()` (which is used in your exemple) is the selector to target the tbody. `$(this).next()`means this (clicked `thead`), find [next](https://api.jquery.com/next/) sibling element (`tbody`).

Answer (score 0):

You will have to change your script and change selectors. Current `$("thead.opening")` will for example select all `<thead class="opening">` tags, so it would have to be similar to this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("thead.opening").click(function () {
        var thisThead = $(this);
        var thisTbody = thisThead.next();
        thisTbody.slideToggle('slow', function () {
            thisThead.toggleClass("active");
            thisThead.find(".imgAccordion").attr("src", thisThead.is('.active') ? "http://placehold.it/30/ffffff/000000" : "http://placehold.it/30/000000/ffffff");
        });
    });
});
```

**[Check this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)** with 2 tables.